# Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "name"' at authors to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

what does it mean?
is there something wrong with the database?

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("authors").orderByChild("name").equalTo(str);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    search_authors author = ds.getValue(search_authors.class);
                    Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "Test", author.name);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                throw  error.toException();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you see is not related to your client-side code, but an optimization that you should make on the server-side (in this case, for the Firebase Realtime Database).

In your code, you use `getReference("authors").orderByChild("name").equalTo(str)`, which says "for all data under '/authors', find the authors with 'name' equal to the given string".

When your client SDK makes this query to the server, it sends back **everything** under `/authors` (if permissions allow it) and says "hey, I don't have an index for 'name', can you deal with it on your end?". The SDK then sifts through the data sent back and pulls out all the documents where 'name' equals the string you gave. It also displays the warning you saw.

During development, this is fine as you are dealing with small amounts of data, but when `/authors` starts to contain hundreds of entries, you end up downloading all of them when you may only need just one of them - this is inefficient. Before deploying your code to the masses, you should add `".indexOn": "name"` to your [security rules in the Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/rules) to build the index needed for this query. How to do this is [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#defining_data_indexes).

As an example, you could use these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "authors": {
      ".read": "auth != null", // any logged in user can read anything under /authors
      ".indexOn": ["name"], // index all authors by the 'name' field
      
      "$authorId": {
        // only the owner can write to their own data
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $authorId", 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After you create such an index, the server can send back only the matching data rather than all of it and the warning stop appearing. Then repeat this for any other fields you plan to query, such as "likeCount", "commentCount", "createdAt", "lastPostAt", and so on *as needed*.

Comment: I am very grateful to you)